# Eclipselink: Count of Entities fetched by a query at all?

Tags: query-optimization, eclipselink

Is it possible to retrieve the count of all entities fetched by a query at all?

The result should not only contain the count of the entities in the result list but the count of all assosiated Entities and their assosiations fetched by the query and loaded into the memory
as well.

I need this trying to optimize the settings to minimize the runtime for queries.

Comment: You might want to check out the profiler and what it is capable of: https://eclipse.dev/eclipselink/documentation/2.5/solutions/performance002.htm

Comment: Thanks for the hint.
A single "find-all" query to a specific Entity with approx. 20.000 Entries created a logfile of more then 12MB. 
Some investigations later I found some OneToMany Relations annotated with FetchType.EAGER. Changing them to FetchType.LAZY solved my Problem.